# iPhone iOS8: UIAlertView upside down rotation doesn't work fine when build from iOS7.1 sdk and run on 8.0 and above devices

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, ios8.1

Any one has any idea how to fix this for iOS 8 device. is it Apple's implementation issue for UIAlertview ?

I am having screen shot for the same. But can not upload due to reputation limit :(

Comment: upload image on dropbox and share link here

Comment: put a breakpoint in willrotatefrominterfaceorientaiton and check for the frame.there will be no change in frame.so it should be with ui not calling any rotation methods.may be you have to check if you are displaying any busy indicators and why alertview is not updating by frames

Answer (score 1):

In IOS8 added UIAlertController instead of UIAlertView

```
if (([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:@"8.0" options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)) {
    // use UIAlertView
}
else {
    // use UIAlertController

[self  showAlert];
}



-(void)showAlert

{
    UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"AlertView" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet;
    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"GO" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    // [action doSomething];

    }];

    UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

Try with that solution.

Comment: As mentioned in the question title , I need to build the app with 7.1 SDk and if I use UIAlertController it will not compile.

Comment: for IOS7.1 use UIAlertView for IOS8 use UIAlertController you have to write condition for  ios7 and ios8

Comment: Here my need is to build the app with 7.1 SDK only. And even if write the code with 8.0+ condition, 7.1 SDK will give compilation error for UIAlertController